# Execute Sabre SOAP Requests without WSDL

Tags: soap, wsdl, soapui, sabre, boomerang-app

I would appreciate if anybody could tell me a suitable App/tool to execute Sabre SOAP Requests without WSDL.

I understand we need to pass WSDL as an URL in order to execute sample SOAP requests in tools like "[Boomerang](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/boomerang-soap-rest-clien/eipdnjedkpcnlmmdfdkgfpljanehloah?hl=en)", "SoapUI" etc.

However my clients have shared their user credentials which is not having any WSDL information, am pretty naive in order to access their CERT endpoints.

NOTE: am having CERT endpoint (URL), EPR, iPCC details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

please go to [Sabre Developer](https://developer.sabre.com/) and register for an account there, you can send a mail to sabre support for activating your account with your credentials, so that you have access to Resource pages, where you get all the wsdl links.

and you can use the tool [Boomerang](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/boomerang-soap-rest-clien/eipdnjedkpcnlmmdfdkgfpljanehloah?hl=en), i use this tool, as this has very user friendly UI, and much better than SoapUI.

Session Create:
[URL](https://developer.sabre.com/docs/soap_apis/session_management/create_session), here you can find all links related to session create.

Thanks.